# Call AngularJS method from Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am using AngularJS and Typescript. There is an external library that i am using and i need to call an AngularJS method from that library which is in vanilla javascript i followed [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/austinnoronha/nukRe/light/)

but sadly it did not work.

The error i get is that the function (which is in the my AngularJS class) is not a function.

```
  var scope = angular.element(
document.
getElementById("MainWrap")).
scope();
scope.$apply(function () {
    scope.createSession(data);
});
```

Now does this have to do with the `vm` that i use in typescript?

Following is the typescript code

```
module MyCtrl{

interface IMyController{
    createSession();
}

class MyController implements IMyController{

    constructor(
        ){

        var vm = this;


    }

    createSession(data){
             console.log(data);
    }
}

angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl', MyController);
```

}

And here goes the HTML

```
<section id="MainWrap">

</section>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scope` is an object that Angular uses to bind the template and the controller. But you can use the syntax `controllerAs` to get rid of the scope and use the controller instance to bind the properties and methods of this, with the template. Once you do that the `scope` of the template will have a property named as the alias you gave to the controller either on the router/directive definition (`controllerAs: alias`), or the template `ng-controller="MyCtrl as alias"`. This property is the controller instance thus you can call your method like that:

```
 var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("MainWrap")).scope();
 scope.$apply(function () {
    scope.ctrlAlias.createSession(data);
 });
```

But if possible encapsulate this in a directive so you don't need to access the angular components from outside your application